# SQL Update based on grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case-sensitive

Our system creates 2 lines per journal number and stamps a segment on each line.

Line 1 is system generated and line 2 is what the user has entered front end.

The issue is the 2nd line of each journal the system populates the segment in the way the user entered it front end, where as the 1st line populates the segment how its stored in the back end - this means we can have case sensitive issues across the journal itself. Not an issue on the journal but causes issues further down the line.

Currently the table looks like below

| HMY | Journal # | Segment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | House |
| 2 | 10001 | HouSE |
| 3 | 10002 | FLAT |
| 4 | 10002 | flat |
| 5 | 10003 | Unit |
| 6 | 10003 | UniT |

The 2nd lines segment of each journal must be updated to match the segment on the 1st line.

Desired end result:

| HMY | Journal # | Segment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | House |
| 2 | 10001 | House |
| 3 | 10002 | FLAT |
| 4 | 10002 | FLAT |
| 5 | 10003 | Unit |
| 6 | 10003 | Unit |

It has to update to how the system populated the segment so if it shows as all capitals, the 2nd line must be all capitals etc.

I have tried various methods but nothing is quite working how I would expect it. For example I was trying to find the min(hmy) grouped by journal number and update the segment of the max(hmy) grouped by journal number but it wouldn't.

Also looked at updating value based on previous row but could not work how I can incorporate that code into my issue.

Comment: Tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Also add ddl for table and insert statements for sample data. There is an excellent service at https://dbfiddle.uk/ that can be used. Create the scenario and update your post with the url

Comment: Every specific DBMS has significantly different syntax, no answer can be given without it.

Comment: Hi all - apologies. Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LAG to get previous value and update:

```sql
update  t
set Segment = PrevSegment
FROM    (
    select  *
    ,   LAG(Segment) OVER(PARTITION BY [Journal #] ORDER BY HMY) AS prevSegment
    FROM    journaltable j
    ) t
WHERE   prevSegment IS NOT NULL -- prevents writing the system generated value
```